# how to add execution time in atom terminal

Tags: python

script output panel doesn't take input from user so I have to use the platformio terminal plugin in atom but it doesn't show the program finished time or execution time, I know, there are some packages to show the execution time like given below. But I don't wanna use the same code in each of my file so is there any way to add if somewhere in the plugin or making some kind of modification in plugin's code file, I have looked up for this but didn't get any relevant solution regarding this. If anyone could please tell me work around this issue.it is necessary to show the execution time in terminal to show the efficiency for the code.

```
import time
starttime=time.time()
for i in range(1,10000):
    print(i)
endtime=round(time.time()-starttime,2)
print(f'Finshed [{endtime}]')
```

Comment: Do you use Unix Based System? Look about "time" command (time python ./your_script.py).

Comment: Okay,Got it ,Thanks